# Is there a new version of Xamarin.OpenId.AppAuth.Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, oauth, okta

I have been following an [Okta tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/01/add-authentication-xamarin-openid-connect) from 2018 (which is the latest I can find) about adding OAuth to a Xamarin Forms and it references Xamarin.OpenId.AppAuth.Android which according to [Nuget](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/XPlat/OpenId) is prerelease (0.7) and also hasn't been updated since 2018.

This package won't work with my Xamarin app as it references an old v4 Android package and newer Xamarin uses v7 or AndroidX stuff.

So - is there a new package (updated <6 months ago) somewhere I can't find? Or is there a different method to do this now and if so - what is it?

Thanks in advance

**First post, happy to edit / add info as needed, please just let me know**

Comment: I do not find the update as well. You could contact the owner on Github https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.OpenId.AppAuth.Android/   or report you requirement in Github Issues. https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues

Comment: For visibility on this, I did contact the owner but no reply. I never found a solution for this other than not using it and building using a completely different method.

Comment: You may use other ways.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth
 or  https://www.davidbritch.com/2020/04/authentication-from-xamarinforms-app.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I have found, there is no direct upgrade for this and the solution is to simply use an alternative method. Personally, due to lack of knowledge in this space, I opted to use a different identity provider who had better support.

Answer (score 0):

There are oauth libraries out there maintained by vendors in the identity and access management space.  But this one seems to be more or less the official library to use with Xamarin apps: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient

It is not maintained by a specific vendor, so it could be used with any of them with the proper configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin provides the ability of creating Xamarin Binding Library for both iOS And Android. You can download the latest AppAuth .AAR file from the Maven Central Repository and create the Xamarin component and use it.

Download AppAuth.AAR file from
https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:appauth

Creating Xamarin Binding Library Walkthrough:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar